# How to start server with port from server.properties rather than yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, port

how to get server port from server.properties rather than .yml?

I have my application which start at port 7799 which is placed in the .yml file in in `/src/main/resources/`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
        addDefaultProfile(app, source);
        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
        log.info("Access URLs:\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
                "Local: \t\thttp://127.0.0.1:{}\n\t" +
                "External: \thttp://{}:{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
            env.getProperty("server.port"),
            InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
            env.getProperty("server.port"));

    }
```

I have server.properties file in location `/config/` where I put all the database parameters.

How to get port from server.properties instead of .yml file?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get any value from properties file.
One way is

You can have a separate class to get all the properties so that everything you will get it from here

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
@PropertySource("classpath:server.properties")
public class ServerProperties {
    private String protocol;
    private String port;
    private String host;

    ...get and set methods here
}
```

and just autowire them in your class by

```
@Autowired
private ServerProperties serverProperties;
```

Second way of getting properties is

```
private static Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(DummyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/server.properties"));
String port = prop.getProperty("server.port");
```

Get port to run the app

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {
private static Properties prop = new Properties();
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
   prop.load(DummyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/server.properties"));
   String port = prop.getProperty("server.port");
   return (container -> {
     container.setPort(port);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get only port from properties file and keep all the rest in .yml?

Comment: By going second way, you can get only port value from properties file

Comment: What to do next? I have port but how can I implement it to app starts with it?

Comment: I don't only want to get port. I want to start my app with port number placed in server.properties.

Comment: Can you try the last part